# Comprehending the meaning and the following structure after But For

Tags: prepositional-phrases

The following sentence is from [the Wall Street Journal](https://www.wsj.com/articles/this-is-your-irs-at-work-tigta-report-treasury-inspector-general-for-tax-administration-audit-inflation-reduction-act-11660943317).

> The new Inflation Reduction Act has many damaging provisions, but for sheer government gall the $80 billion reward to the Internal Revenue Service stands out.

I can't comprehend after *but for*. I understand that the editorial writer thinks that the act is bad **and** the reward too. And as a prepositional phrase *but for* should be followed by noun or similar one but there is a verbal phrase which is *stands out*. So I got to see *but for* not as the common usage which usually means *if not* or *except for*.

Should I seperate *but* and *for* like this?

> The act is bad for most of tax payers, **but** good **for** the sheer and gall government, **and** that point stands out.

or

> If there were not gall of the sheer govenrment, the act is bad, and the reward stands out.

I think the latter rephrasing doesn't make sense.

Comment: "as a prepositional phrase but for should be followed by noun" - It *is* followed by a noun phrase: *sheer government gall*.  Did you look up the word *gall*?

Comment: @stangdon Yes. I know *gall* means *imprudence*. So do you think that *except for gall of the sheer government, the act is damaging.*?

Comment: Not exactly.  **But** does not mean *except* here - it's like "My brothers are all tall, **but** Han is the tallest."  It is not negating the first part of the sentence, only adding to it.

Comment: _Impudence_, not _imprudence_! (They have different meanings.) _Sheer_ describes the gall, not the government.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*For sheer government gall* means *as an example of complete gall (impudent behaviour) on the part of the government.* They are saying that the reward to the Internal Revenue Service is a notable instance of this. It is one of the ways in which the Act is harmful.

Comment: +1 and to make clear that "but for" isn't a structure here at all. It's "but" as a normal conjunction, then "for sheer government gall" as a separate structure as Kate describes